# How do I pass a property expression back to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that displays a table of data that I want to be able to sort by specifying a property on the row type.

My model (so far) is:

```
class Model
{
    List<DataType> data;
    Expression<Func<DataType, object>> SortProperty;
}
```

I've tried creating that in the view to be passed into my controller as follows:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("Index", "Approvals", new IndexModel() { Page = Model.Page, SortProperty = ((ApprovalModel m) => m.Id)}) %>'>Id</a>
```

which renders as:

```
<a href='/PartsLegislation/Approvals.aspx/Approvals?SortProperty=m%20%3D%3E%20Convert(m.Id)'>Id</a>
```

so it sort of looks like it'll work (all-be-it with a `Convert` expression in there), however in the controller `SortProperty` is always `null`.

---

**TL;DR:** How can I pass an expression pointing to a property from my view to the controller?

---

**Edit:** My controller action is as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Model viewModel)
{
    ....
    viewModel.Approvals = PartsDC.Repository<Approval>()
                             .Where(a => !a.Deleted)
                             .OrderBy(viewModel.SortExpression)
                             .Skip((viewModel.Page ?? 0) * RowsPerPage)
                             .Take(RowsPerPage)
                             .Select(a => Mapper.Map<Approval, ApprovalHeaderModel>(a))
                             .ToList();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does your `ApprolvationController.Index()` method look like?

Comment: lol, my interest was mostly the method signature and not the implementation.

Comment: Serializing and deserializing an `Expression` is way more work than I can imagine it being worth for this usage. There are libraries for it (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization, for example), but you're going to be better off just passing the string name of the property and building the expression on the controller side.

Comment: @haim770: Edited (again).

Comment: @SteveRuble: That's what I'm starting to realise, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't pass complex objects via URL. You can pass for example string with name of property.
However if you want to just sort table maybe you should think about another approach to this problem. Check this http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ .
It allows you to simply sort your table by clicking on headers.

Comment: Currently I'm looking at simply passing a string then re-constructing the sort expression based one that so I can pass it to `OrderBy`. I can't easily use a table sorter javascript style as the data is (effectively) infinite and i'm paging it in with ajax.